# use def in order to print a lot of values

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, key, definition

I have a form like this

```
a={'vladimirputin': {'milk': 2.87, 'parsley': 1.33, 'bread': 0.66}, 
'barakobama': {'parsley': 0.76, 'sugar': 1.98, 'crisps': 1.09, 
'potatoes': 2.67, 'cereal': 9.21}}
```

and i want to transform like this

```
milk 
---- 
 vladimirputin: 2.87 

cereal 
------ 
 barakobama: 9.21 

bread 
----- 
 vladimirputin: 0.66 

potatoes 
-------- 
 barakobama: 2.67 

sugar 
----- 
 barakobama: 1.98 

parsley 
------- 
 vladimirputin: 1.33 barakobama: 0.76 

crisps 
------ 
 barakobama: 1.09
```

but by using def i do not Know how to present so many values with only one def.All the necessary values are calculated but i do not know how to use them.

This is my progress until now

```
for key in d.keys():
    print(key)
    length=len(key)
    print(length)
    products=d[key]
    for price in products.values():
        for name,valuen in products.items():
            if valuen == price:
                print("\t",name,":",price,end="\t")
    print("\n")
```

Comment: start by inverting your `dict`, since it's exactly backwards of the format you need.  Then printing is easy, no?

Comment: but i want to print all those elements through a def,@roippi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dictYou can do this also:

```
def get_invert_dict(dict):
  {c:{key:v} for key,value in a.iteritems() for c,v in value.iteritems()}

#Test the function
new_dict = get_invert_dict(a)
print(new_dict)
```

Edit: Doesn't work if multiple value for the same key (ex: persil). The last one is used as value

Answer (score 0):

This answer relies on my answer to your previous question. After getting `b` , the inverted dictionary, as explained in my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23395509/531036), you can get your output with this code:

```
def print_data(b):
    for key, value in b.items():
        print key
        print '-' * len(key)
        for k, v in value.items():
            print ' {}: {}'.format(k, v),
        print '\n'
```

This gives:

```
cereal
------
 barakobama: 9.21

potatoes
--------
 barakobama: 2.67

parsley
-------
 vladimirputin: 1.33  barakobama: 0.76

sugar
-----
 barakobama: 1.98

crisps
------
 barakobama: 1.09

milk
----
 vladimirputin: 2.87

bread
-----
 vladimirputin: 0.66
```

Note that the order of food items in your expected output and my answer is not the same. This is because dictionaries are not ordered by default. You might need to explore [OrderedDicts](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if order of elements is a concern.

Documentation on [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Comment: if you run my code you will see that all the necessary elements are created but the problem is how to use my code within a def and present at the same time all those prints.In addition,when i use the count is in order to find out how many _ i need to create in order to cover the heading each time,,again thank you for your help

Comment: @user3573361 Updated my answer to address both of your queries.

Comment: thank you once again,@shaktimaan,there is only one problem can you explain me why at the end it prints tha word "None")                        milk
----
  vladimirputin : 2.87 

cereal
------
  barakobama : 9.21 

potatoes
--------
  barakobama : 2.67 

sugar
-----
  barakobama : 1.98 

parsley
-------
  vladimirputin : 1.33   barakobama : 0.76 

crisps
------
  barakobama : 1.09 

bread
-----
  vladimirputin : 0.66 

None